# Test Cases Fail On Null Assertion

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unit-testing

```
"packages": [
           {
             "TriggerType": "sample",
             "StatusDescription": "",
             "Score": null,
             "Percentile": null,
             "Band": ""
           }
         ]
```

When I parse this JSON using `JObject attachmentData = JObject.Parse(targetPayload);`

and perform the unit testing.

```
Assert.AreEqual("", attachmentData.SelectToken("packages")[0].SelectToken("Score").ToString());
```

**This works fine but I want to check**

```
Assert.AreEqual(null, attachmentData.SelectToken("packages")[0].SelectToken("Score").ToString());

or 
Assert.IsNull(attachmentData.SelectToken("packages")[0].SelectToken("Score").ToString());
```

**These are giving the following errors.**

```
Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<(null)>. Actual:<>

{"Assert.IsNull failed. "}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you trying to compare `null` with `ToString()`? In general this should never work (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring)

Comment: It is quite unlikely that `ToString` will return `null`. Have you considered deserialising to a concrete class rather than using `SelectToken` erc?

Comment: We cannot use the concrete class for it

Comment: Why can't you use a concrete class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `JToken`'s `Value` or `HasValue`:

```
var score = o.SelectToken("packages")[0].SelectToken("Score");

// score.Value is null
// score.IsValue is false
```

In your test:

```
Assert.AreEqual(null, attachmentData.SelectToken("packages")[0].SelectToken("Score").Value);
```

Please note that if there is no `score` (or `packages`) this will throw and you may want:

```
Assert.AreEqual(null, attachmentData.SelectToken("packages")?[0]?.SelectToken("Score")?.Value);
```

This depends what you are trying to check:

1. Score is there but the value is null
2. Just to ensure that there is no score (so null or lack of presence are both OK
3. Something else.

---

> I want to check the score is there and value is null

```
var score = attachmentData.SelectToken("packages")?[0]?.SelectToken("Score");
Assert.IsNotNull(score);
Assert.IsFalse(score.Value<string>());
```

Or

```
Assert.IsNotNull(score);
var v = (JValue)score;
Assert.IsNull(v.Value);
```

Comment: Thanks! but I need  this to work and can you this type of assertion
Assert.AreEqual(null, attachmentData.SelectToken("packages")[0].SelectToken("Score").ToString());

Comment: I want to check the score is there and value is null

Comment: Tried using this but doesnt work for me

            var score = attachmentData.SelectToken("packages")[0].SelectToken("Score");
            Assert.IsNotNull(score);
            Assert.IsNull(score.Values());

Comment: This means that when i tried using the code above it doesnt work and giving the same error every time.

Assert.IsNull(score.Value); this is giving compile error and Assert.IsNull(score.Values())
and this fails

Comment: @SrikrishnaSharma Sorry I updated the code. I think `score.Value<string>()` is your best option.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231720/discussion-between-srikrishna-sharma-and-tymtam).

Comment: Assert.AreEqual(null, attachmentData.SelectToken("packages")[0].SelectToken("Percentile").Value<string>());